# Nested RecyclerView won't show

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am trying to create a RecyclerView withing a NestedScrollView but the RecyclerView won't display.

This is my XML layout:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.yarkoni.anybody.activities.OffersActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_offers">

    <!-- A RecyclerView with some commonly used attributes -->
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/offerContent_recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
        android:scrollbars="vertical" />
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

This is my Activity:

```
final LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
layoutManager.setAutoMeasureEnabled(false);
offersRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

ArrayList<Offer> offerList = new ArrayList<>();
offerList.add(new Offer("Lorem"));
offerList.add(new Offer("Lorem"));
OffersAdapter offersAdapter = new OffersAdapter(offerList);
offersRecyclerView.setAdapter(offersAdapter);
offersRecyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
```

Comment: The best way to debug issues like this is assign a fixed height to the RecyclerView first, make sure it is properly displaying first. Also curious why you have a Match/Match RecyclerView inside a ScrollView, it seems like one of them is extraneous.

Answer (score 0):

Try by giving the recyclerview fixed height.